# Does $f(z)=\frac{(z-k)^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}$ have a removable singularity in $z=k\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having trouble with a problem of my complex analysis course. The original problem was a bit difficult for me, but I found a solution to it if the above is true. However, I'm not able to prove it. If it happens to be false, then it I would have to look into something different. The reason I think it is true is purely based on a lot of graphs I've plotted. But these can be false, since it is pretty hard with complex functions.

So far I've tried to prove that the function is bounded around $z=k$ and I've also tried evaluating $\lim_\limits{z\rightarrow k} \frac{(z-k)^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}$ using both $\sin(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{z^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$ and $\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$, but both options didn't really help in any way. Using the series I thought that it might be possible to divide the numerator and denominator of our function by $(z-k)^2$ so that it would be possible to evaluate the limit, which didn't really work out. Using the other definition of $\sin$ I couldn't think of anything that helped.

Eventually I tried using $z=k+\varepsilon$, for some $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{C}$ so that I could take the limit to $0$. But this didn't help me. Can anyone help me with the problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by periodicity we have that
$$f(z)=\frac{(z-k)^2}{\sin^2(\pi(z-k))}$$
The fact that the singularity is removable should now be clear from the limit
$$\lim_{x\to k}\frac{x-k}{\sin(\pi(x-k))}=\frac 1{\pi}$$

Comment: Yes it is, thank you so much!

Comment: @Barry Sure thing, Flash.